# Pt-archiver csv double quote missing for some fields

Tags: mysql, innodb, archive

I am trying to use pt-archive to archive my database. Below is my script for the archiving process.

```
pt-archiver --source h=localhost,D=***,t=** --user=*** --password=**** --where "dateTime<'2022-07-01 00:00:00'" --limit=1000 --progress=1000 --txn-size=1000 --statistics  --no-check-charset --no-delete --file="/usr/local/test1.dat" --output-format=csv
```

Below is an example of the output line

0, 2, 0, 0, 1, "2022-05-26 01:46:54", "2022-05-26 19:27:15", "-1.22706831", 36.70828247, 0, 0, 0, 2674.4, 0, 0.000, 1, 1, 0, 0

See this field "-1.22706831" it has double quote whereas this one does not have 36.70828247. So should I stick to the default file which generate space among the fields? In the long run which one will be more effective to maintain?

Answer (score 1):

**If the goal is to "archive" the data, ...**

In general, a quoted (single or double quotes) number works just fine when used as any numeric datatype.

As for why?  I don't know.  I suspect minus (`-`) triggered the need for quotes.  Perhaps floating numbers like `12e3` or `1.2e-3` will get quotes, too.

`true`, `false`, `NULL` -- these had better not be quoted.

**Solution**

Add a space; change

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

to

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ', '
```

The clue was hard to see, but it was in the `WARNINGS`:

```
Incorrect datetime value: ' "2022-05-26 01:46:54"' for column 'dateTime' at row 1
```

Notice how, for example

```
0, 2, 0, 0, 1, "2022-05-26 02:06:54", "2022-05-26 19:27:17", "-1.22706831", 36.70828247, 0, 0, 0, 2674.4, 0, 0.000, 1, 1, 0, 0
```

always has a space after the comma.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142271/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-james-pt-archiver-csv-double-quote-missing-for-some).

Answer (score 1):

**If the goal is to Delete *most* of a table...**

If you have 24 months' worth of data now but want to delete down to only 3 months' worth, then the best approach, by far, is to copy over the data you want to keep.

```
CREATE TABLE tmp (...,
    PRIMARY KEY(...)   -- with the `PRIMARY KEY` but no other `INDEXes`
    )
    PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(...)), ...
--    include about 15 weekly partitions (as discussed in my blog)
-- because you will be deleting more data in the future,
-- Stop writing to `real`
INSERT INTO tmp
    SELECT * FROM real;
ALTER TABLE tmp
    ADD   ((the desired secondary indexes));
RENAME TABLE real TO old,
             tmp TO real;
-- test things, then
-- allow writing to real
DROP TABLE old;
```

Note that the `INSERT...SELECT` avoids the need for `pt-archiver`.

My [*Partitioning*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) blog    .

Comment: but before that I would like to archive first the last 24 months data. Is it correct to do it via pt-archive first ? Also after that I do delete via pt-archive thereafter I follow you above method ? Correct me if I am wrong in my steps ?

Comment: @user8012596 - I'm confused.  Are there two things going on?  1. "Archiving" the data. and 2. "deleting" "old" data?

Comment: yes 1. I want to archive those say 21 Months data and just keep last 3 months data. 2. You are right I wanna delete that 21 Months data which from now on wards is to keep just latest 3 months data. Hope I am cleearer.

Comment: Once you have created the new version of the table with just the recent 3 months, you have all the time in the world to archive or dump or whatever, the old 21 months.  Deleting 3 months from the 24 will be fast, but probably unnecessary.  Simply use mysqldump or pt-archiver or whatever to dump just the 21 months.

Comment: thank you now I am clear and confirmed with the steps first build the new table with 24 partitions there after as I pt-archive each month then I will drop the partitions right.

Comment: No, only 5 partitions; you don't need the other 21.  No, use `DROP PARTITION` each month, plus `REORGANIZE PARTITION future INTO ..., future`.  [_Partition_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

Comment: Based on your 5 partition in your blog is this how the script is to PARTITION BY RANGE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateTime)) (
        PARTITION start        VALUES LESS THAN (0),
        PARTITION p11_2022 VALUES LESS THAN (unix_timestamp('2022-12-01 00:00:00')),
        PARTITION p12_2022 VALUES LESS THAN (unix_timestamp('2023-01-01 00:00:00')),
        PARTITION p01_2023 VALUES LESS THAN (unix_timestamp('2023-02-01 00:00:00')),
        PARTITION future       VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);? But wouldnt this partition  p11_2022 will consist of all the rest of the 2 years data in it too ?

Comment: @user8012596 - I thought you only wanted to keep 3 months in the table, and remove the other 21?  Please edit the Question to  make it clear what you have now and what you want going forward.

Comment: ok let me clear for now I have data of the year 2021,2022 and as present Jan 2023. So moving forward I want to store only the last 3 months of data. For example if once I am in Feb 2023 my plan is to keep Nov 2022, Dec2022 and Jan 2023. So moving forward this how I will slide accordingly

Comment: is the above clear or am I still confusing ? Hope I am clear with my explanation and how I am going to move forward.

Comment: I did this exercise just now surprisingly after all the process finish and rename I notice suddenly the new table and old table has same size ? Is there any reason for this ?

Comment: I try to run this command SELECT (data_length+index_length)/power(1024,3) tablesize_gb
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='mydb' and table_name='mytable';

Comment: the new table actually got around 12 million rows only compare to the old table has more than 40 million rows

Comment: Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE tablename` before and after.

Comment: I am not sure about before and after but I put here in the pastebin https://pastebin.com/YshVX9hX of both new and old table. Surprising the new table show much larger but it only around 12Mil in the partitions when I total up.

Comment: @user8012596 - What was the `WHERE` clause when you copied the 3 months' data into the new table?

Comment: Here it is INSERT INTO iotdttemp SELECT * FROM iotdt where gDateTime>'2022-10-15 23:59:59'; I just took from mid of october. But when I do select count(gDateTime) from iodt (I mean the new table its around 12 Mil). So its quite weird right ?

Comment: Yes, something is weird.  Was `iotdttemp` empty when you started that `INSERT`?

Comment: Yes I created via the command line build it first with the primary key.

Comment: I also find it weird why it has like the old details but I have confirmed it has no previous data only from 16th Oct 2022. What else should I check ?

Comment: Count number of rows per day:  `SELECT LEFT(gDateTime, 10), COUNT(*) FROM iotdttemp GROUP BY 1;` -- maybe the numbers will point to an anomaly to investigate.  Or maybe there will be more than 90 days.

Comment: here is the result of the query https://pastebin.com/XBWFt3sN. You see there is no date before 16th October 2022 which correct according to what I select and insert ? Very weird ya.

Comment: did you had time to review this result here pastebin.com/XBWFt3sN.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like what it should.  I'm stumped.

Comment: what could cause data and index size to be like the original is it due to naming ?

Comment: what will be your best advice should I repeat the whole process again ? Create new table and move data from this move table itself ?